# How to write To and From date in a MySql Query method?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I would like to know how to write a SQL query to select `#from` and `#to` any date within a MySql table.
I know how to `SELECT *FROM table` but struggle to know how to `SELECT from` and to any dates so then a user would be able to select using a datepicker, this is code from my PHP also jQuery for the datepicker.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN ('2015-00-00 00:00:00') AND ('2015-00-00 23:59:00')";
 $( "#from" ).datepicker();
 $( "#to" ).datepicker();
 $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT00:00:00'});
 $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyT23:59:59'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (time BETWEEN '2015-00-00 00:00:00' AND '2015-00-00 23:59:00')
```

Make sure you're using a `DATETIME` field so MySQL can search efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but im still getting Error can you see what im doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried the query here and it works great. Could you perhaps tell me what the error was? :)

Comment: $Tim = $_GET['time'];
  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE (time BETWEEN '2015-00-00 00:00:00' AND '2015-00-00 23:59:00')";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  //if we got some result 
  if(isset($check)){
  //displaying success 
  echo "success";
  }else{
  //displaying failure
  echo "failure";
   }
 
  mysqli_close($con);

Comment: Yes sorry,  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: That's the error from PHP. Could you try running the query in MySQL Monitor and seeing what you get back? Or echoing `mysqli_error($con)`?

Comment: Sorry Im new to this have I put the mysqli_error($con) in wrong place.syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_error' (T_STRING) in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98444/discussion-between-twostraws-and-john-boy).

Comment: Thanks for helping me get the DATETIME data from table TwoStraws A++, Now just need a little help with, How to write from and to into the query. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you. Please mark it as correct so others can benefit, then post a fresh question to ask about writing queries – no one will look this far down the comments!